# template works fine whereas templateUrl not in angular component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angular-templatecache

[code to create tabs component](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks)
Hi,I am learning angular component from this link ,the problem is when i tried to load from external files  instead of template it throws following error

```
angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined
    at controller.selectTab (scr.js:47)
    at controller.$postLink (scr.js:50)
    at angular.js:9228
    at forEach (angular.js:329)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9225)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8510)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8390)
    at angular.js:1756
```

here is the scr.js code

```
var tab = {
  bindings: {
    label: '@'
  },
  require: {
    tabs: '^^tabs'
  },
  transclude: true,
 template:['$templateCache',function($templateCache){
  return $templateCache.get('tab.html') 
  }
  ],

  controller: function () {
    this.$onInit = function () {
        this.tab = {
        label: this.label,
        selected: false
      };
      this.tabs.addTab(this.tab);
    };
  }
};

var tabs = {
    bindings: {
    selected: '@'
  },
  transclude: true,
   template:['$templateCache',function($templateCache){
  return $templateCache.get('tab.html') 
  }
  ],    
  controller: function () {
      this.$onInit = function () {
        this.tabs = [];
    };
    this.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
      this.tabs.push(tab);
    };
    this.selectTab = function selectTab(index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
        this.tabs[i].selected = false;
      }
      this.tabs[index].selected = true;
    };
    this.$postLink = function () {
        this.selectTab(this.selected);
      console.log(this.selected)
    };
  },

};

angular
    .module('app', [])
  .component('tab', tab)
  .component('tabs', tabs);
```

Here is html code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scr.js"></script>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font: 300 14px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #111;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs {
  margin: 25px;
  background: #fff;
}
.tabs__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.tabs__list li {
  float: left;
}
.tabs__list li a {
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.tabs__content {
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <tabs selected="2">
      <tab label="Tab 1">
        Tab 1 contents!
       </tab>
       <tab label="Tab 2">
        Tab 2 contents!
       </tab>
       <tab label="Tab 3">
        Tab 3 contents!
       </tab>
    </tabs>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here are two template which i am trying to load in component tab.html and tabs.html respectively:

```
    <div class="tabs__content" ng-if="$ctrl.tab.selected">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>

<div class="tabs">
      <ul class="tabs__list">
        <li ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.tabs">
          <a href="" 
            ng-bind="tab.label" 
            ng-click="$ctrl.selectTab($index);"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tabs__content" ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
```

can any one please help me fix this,Thanks in advance

Comment: get(tab.html) would need to be a path and not just the file name. so is your tab.html is located in the same folder where your file is?

Comment: all the files are located in same foloder

Comment: Index.html? In the same folder too?

Comment: Yes index.html,tab.html,tabs.html,js file all are in same folder